# Boosting randomized algorithms with Hoeffding's inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working on Ex. 2.2.8 out of Roman Vershinyn's High Dimensional Probability book: https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

The problem asks: Imagine we have an algorithm for solving a decision problem. Suppose the algorithm makes the decision at random and returns the correct answer with probability $1/2 + \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. To improve the performance, we run the algorithm $N$ times and take the majority vote. Show that, for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, the answer is correct with probability $1 - \epsilon$ as long as $N \geq 2 \delta^{-2} \ln (\epsilon^{-1})$.

The hint was to set $X_i$ to the indicator function on the event that the algorithm guessed incorrectly and apply Hoeffding's inequality. However, in this section he gives variations of Hoeffding's inequality, one for symmetric bernoulli random variables (along with its two sided inequality) and for general bounded random variables (which is asked to be proven in the previous exercise). Ultimately, I think I want to show that $$\mathbb{P}\left\{\text{event that the algorithm guessed incorrectly a majority of the time}\right\} \leq \epsilon$$ as long as $N \geq 2\delta^{-2}\ln(\epsilon^{-1})$ but I am not sure how to formulate this properly with the Hoeffding inequalities introduced since $X_i$ is not symmetric. Would anyone be able to provide a hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: Your restatement of the problem looks good.  If you have the Hoeffding inequality for bounded random variables, why can't you apply it to a Bernoulli r.v. with parameter $\epsilon$?

Comment: So here's the way it is stated: Let $X_i \in [N]$ be independent random variables. Suppose $X_i \in [m_i,M_i]$ for all $i$. Then for all $t \geq 0$, $$\mathbb{P} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \mathbb{E} X_i) \geq t\right\} \leq \exp \left(- \frac{2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^N (M_i - m_i)^2}\right).$$

Comment: in our case, $X_i \in [0,1]$ and $\mathbb{E} X_i = \mathbb{P}\left\{\text{algorithm guesses incorrectly}\right\} = 1/2-\delta$ so we would have that $$\mathbb{P}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - 1/2+\delta) \geq t\right\} \leq \exp \left(-2t^2\right).$$ Here is where I'm not sure what the appropriate $t$ would be @Titus

Comment: First comment should say "Let $X_i$ for $i \in [N]$ be independent random variables."

Comment: Actually, $\sum (M_i - m_i)^2 = \sum 1 = N$, so we should have $2t^2/N$ in your exponential.  So for the algorithm to have a $majority$ of incorrect guesses, we need $ \sum X_i > N/2$, or $$ \sum_{i=1}^N \left( X_i - 1/2 + \delta \right) \geq N/2 - N(1/2 - \delta) = \delta N. $$ Plugging in, your bound becomes $ \exp\left(-2\delta^2 N \right),$ which is what you want, up to a fishy factor of 2.

Comment: Oh of course that should have been $N$ thank you! That is a strange factor of $2$ though. If that's the case, can't the lower bound on $N$ be tightened, i.e. if $N \geq (1/2)\delta^{-2}\ln(\epsilon^{-1})$, then $$\mathbb{P}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - 1/2 + \delta) \geq \delta N\right\} \leq \exp(-2\delta^2N) \leq \epsilon$$ since $$N \geq \frac{\delta^{-2}\ln(\epsilon^{-1})}{2} \Longrightarrow e^{-2\delta^2 N} \leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: Right, I'm wondering if the 2 in your Hoeffding inequality belongs in the denominator if the exponent.